# AWS MySQL RDS becomes unresponsive time to time

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

We have two MySQL RDS instances (Master and read replica). As usual we write to the master and read from the slave.

Master server works fine, but we observed that slave server becomes unresponsive time to time. 
Observations:

[Monitoring Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPyLQ.png)

1. CPU utilization drops down to 0
2. Increase in number of connections
3. Write IOPS, read IOPS, queue depth, write throughput, write latency and read latency drop to 0.

This can be resolved with a restart, but we are interested in finding the root cause. Basically when this happens, we can still log in to mysql prompt, but we can't execute any queries. AWS console shows instance as healthy, no errors are shown.

According to the graphs, there is no any abnormal activity or increase in resource utilization just before this happens. Everything looks normal. 
(Small climbs in the attached graphs are normal. Those are in line with the business pattern. Historically instance survived against larger mountains)

Please let me know if you happen to come across such a situation.

Thanks.

**Note:**

Instance Information

db.m4.xlarge

IOPS 2000

Size 50G

Basically, instance is being under utilized when the issue happens

Note: 
If we wait without restarting the instance, it gets restarted automatically with following error.

```
MySQL restart initiated to address MySQL induced log backup issues. Note that as part of this resulution, a DB Snapshot will be performed after MySQL completes restarting.
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: MySQL replication is not performing data synchronisation, in fact, it is events redo. The best way is check what is carry out during that time frame that cause the the problem. (perhaps a massive batch process on master?)
https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/02/07/overview-of-different-mysql-replication-solutions/

Comment: Hi mootmoot, We have already checked that. No any significant utilization was observed in master database during that time. We can't map this incident with the resource utilization. This comes out of nowhere.

Comment: In addition, for your provisioned IOPS, you should check out Mysql RDS pricing on per GB baselines IOPS vs provisioned IOPS
50GB will give you 50 x 3 IOPS = 150 IOPS.  RDS has a ridiculous  0.119 per IOPS-Month . So just allocate 667GB disk space, you will get max 2001 IOPS , way cheaper than you pay for provisioned IOPS.

Comment: Is the slave server using same storage class ?

Comment: Hi mootmoot, Actually 50G is the database size. We have allocated 500G for the instance. Yes, same class ( Provisioned IOPS - SSD )

Comment: Replication is cpu bound, perhaps devils is in the little details
https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/01/09/how-does-mysql-replication-really-work/
https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/09/22/fighting-mysql-replication-lag/